# Error: socket hang up - Lambda nodejs function http post request

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a very simple function in Lambda using Nodejs.

The purpose of that function is to triggered a third party api every 1 minute.

So for that I have setup Cloud Watch Cron based event.

But that Api is throwing this error:

```
START RequestId: 54d90c9d-0a5b-4e5e-a26a-857d9bb6dd4e Version: $LATEST
2022-08-29T11:11:59.112Z    54d90c9d-0a5b-4e5e-a26a-857d9bb6dd4e    ERROR   Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:692:14)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:478:23)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
```

It works fine in a simple nodejs code on my local machine.

Here is my Lambda Function code:

```
const https = require('https');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    var postData = JSON.stringify({
      "client_id": "abnbfye9-qtfnf1cj-abhrhzfyf7-m2tup-6x9kk2kc5688",
      "client_secret": "fpghfh329-polk80s-ye043465p1yy-45hxnfd874z06",
      "inTime": new Date(),
      "outTime": new Date()
    });
  
    var options = {
      hostname: 'example.com',
      path: '/api/updateDataLambda',
      method: 'POST',
      port: 443, // ️ replace with 80 for HTTP requests
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiJ0ekpFTlNxcDJXeXh4YlNGbSIsImFjY2Vzc1Rva2VuRXhwIjp7ImRhdGUiOiIyMDIyLTA5LTI4IiwidGltZSI6IjA2OjIwOjQ1IiwidGltZVN0YW1wIjoxNjY0MzQ2MDQ1NjQ2LCJnbXQiOiIrMDAwMCJ9LCJyZWZyZXNoVG9rZW5FeHAiOnsiZGF0ZSI6IjIwMjItMDktMjgiLCJ0aW1lIjoiMDY6MjA6NDUiLCJ0aW1lU3RhbXAiOjE2NjQzNDYwNDU2NDYsImdtdCI6IiswMDAwIn0sImlhdCI6MTY2MTc1NDA0NSwiZXhwIjoxNjYxNzU0MTA1fQ.g1e5S15Q1qxB5_s4j3LFfFf6spU8gwgBUyVNLVuWNWk'
      }
    };
  
    var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
      console.log('headers:', res.headers);
  
      res.on('data', (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
      });
    });
  
    req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
  
    req.write(postData);
    req.end();
    
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: isn't your code returning prematurely?

Comment: @TejashwiKalpTaru I dont need to return anything, I just want the api to be hit every one minute

Comment: have you checked the logs for execution runtime? I guess before the request can complete, it's terminating the execution causing the ECONNRESET error, https://dashbird.io/blog/aws-lambda-process-exited-before-completing-request/